# Proper way to link to a subdomain of the current URL in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink, subdomain

What is a proper way to create a link to a subdomain of the current URL, in Drupal 7?

I.e. if I'm on **http://example.com/content123**, the link would point to **http://subdomain.example.com/content123**, thus keeping the current url, only adding a subdomain.

Comment: In what context? Links are typically a *client-side* choice. Where does PHP factor in?

Comment: It's in Drupal. I need a <a href> link to switch to a different language of the same content, i.e. es.example.com/abc... i would still need to keep the same uri

Comment: That's unfortunate, since both of those observations are entirely needed to answer this question. `:|`

Comment: I had a tough time understanding the q'n, sorry... Do you mean, links are not processed on the server-side? If there is a way to do redirect without the use of PHP, that would be even better!

Comment: If there is a way to point to a subdomain, keeping the current path, like <a href='etc...'>abc</a> it would even be better... but how?

Comment: You should specify in your question that you are using Drupal and you want to link to the same content but in a different language. Drupal has a function that will create the url for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take here. The first example I have shown will allow you to get to the root domain and append a new subdomain. The second example will just append a new subdomain to the current host.

**Add subdomain to root domain**

```
<?php
$new_subdomain = 'subdomain';
$split_domain = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo $new_subdomain.'.'.$split_domain[count($split_domain) - 2].'.'.$split_domain[count($split_domain) - 1];
?>
```

**Add subdomain to current host**

```
<?php
$new_subdomain = 'subdomain';
echo $new_subdomain.'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>
```

Comment: You're on a right track, but that's a lot of processing on the server-side for each link. Anything shorter or more natural?

Comment: Do you really think anything shorter is going to actually be easier on the server? Just because there are less lines of code doesn't make it less processing. If you're running drupal, I wouldn't lose sleep over a few string concats.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/url/7) function in Drupal. It allows you to create a link to a path, in a specific language.

> 'language': An optional language object. If the path being linked to is internal to the site, $options['language'] is used to look up the alias for the URL. If $options['language'] is omitted, the global $language_url will be used.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I couldn't figure out how to enter the link text. I also tried l($title, $path, array('language' => 'de')), but id didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a multilingual Drupal site up and running. I tried on one with only one language but I got just the normal address, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is some kind of .htaccess or similar, since using PHP for this matter isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The most "proper" way to handle alternate language pages is client-side, using:

```
 <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
```

Any modern browser should handle the rest.

I'm positive Drupal will insert these for you, if you google hreflang drupal.

Here it is:

http://drupal.org/node/1200030